# Including Application's user-defined-functions into modules

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, lucee

My application for simplistic purposes has

- Application

  - include `functions.cfm`
  - a cache object `application.o`

    - `cfcomponent` modules each with create/update/view a model type

      - each compent includes `functions.cfm` so that it may use them, resulting in each module containing UDFs that they don't use.
      - an example would be

        - `application.o.items = new cfcs.items()`

          - includes `functions.cfm`
        - `application.o.categories = new cfcs.categories()`

          - includes `functions.cfm`

The result is that each of the 10 modules is duplicating the entirety of `functions.cfm` into each module.

I've re-engineered, turning functions into a component (it's named `application._`, which is copied into `variarables._` inside each module and calling the functions like `_.myUDF()` which should be calling `application._` *by reference* rather than recreating every function in the file for every component.

This should be the faster and lightest way to do this, shouldn't it? Can anyone suggest enhancements to this style, or give reasons why `include` might be preferrable, beyond the need to recreate the component if I change add functions to the component `functions.cfc`?

Comment: You might be interested in reading [about Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file `functions.cfm` was included in your CFC files, so you can then call `functionA()` within any of those CFCs.

If you convert to `functions.cfc` and inject that object into your other CFCs, then you'll have to reference the `functions` objects within your other CFC files:

`<cfset functions.functionA()>`

So that's a lot of code to refactor.

Seems like you should `extend` your existing CFCs with `functions.cfc`:

`<cfcomponent extends="cfc.functions">`

This makes your other components ***child objects*** of `functions.cfc`, which therefore inherit the contents of `functions.cfc`. Now, from within any child CFC, you can call `functionA()` as you had when you included `functions.cfm`.

If that's more in line with what you want and you want ALL of your CFCs to include these functions, you can pull a totally ***baller*** move and update your CF server's core `component.cfc` from which all CFCs are extended. This file should be found in `<CF_ROOT>\WEB-INF\cftags`. I've done this in the past to add additional "native" functions to ColdBox applicaitons. Just make sure you track those changes in source control.

Comment: It actually wasn't a lot of code to refactor fortunately. Because of a personal naming convention, beginning each UDF with an underscore (`_MyThing()`), I was able to lift function names from `functions.cfm`, a backup and regex saved the day. // But you're right that extending a base component, something I already do, was probably a more natural way to do it.

Comment: I meant to come back to this answer, but never did. The problem with extending is that, here, it's effectively the same as include. Copying all of your functions to each individual node. Too bad we can't write to the function namespace on a per-application basis

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you already moved all your functions from `functions.cfm` to a component called `functions.cfc`? So your `functions.cfc` looks like this:

```
component {

    function doSomething()    { ... }
    function doAnotherThing() { ... }
    ...

}
```

Now let's go to the place where you initialize the components:

```
// create an instance of your "functions" component.
helperFunctions          = new functions();

// pass this instance to the others components using the constructor
// (components are passed by reference, so make sure your "functions" component is stateless)
application.o.items      = new cfcs.items(helperFunctions);
application.o.categories = new cfcs.categories(helperFunctions);
```

And this is how your `items.cfc` and `categories.cfc` should look like:

```
component {

    function init(functionsInstance) {

        // keep the reference to the "functions" component
        variables._ = arguments.functionsInstance;
    }

    function someFunction() {

        // use the passed "functions" component's functions
        variables._.doSomething();
        variables._.doAnotherThing();
    }

    ...

}
```

Now if you change something in your components, you simply have to run the "initialize routine" again. This will update/override the components stored in the `application.o` struct. So put these lines in a separate file to be included on application start and in the "restart" template you call whenever you need a live update.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `include` method should (as I understand it) allow you to make on the fly updates to the files, and have them reflect instantly without restarting the application. While storing them as an object in the `application scope`, would require restarting the application to refresh them. But is it important to have this ability? It's generally bad practice to be frequently altering the code in a production environment.

Loading `functions.cfm` into a variable would place it in memory, which means it would be present as long as the application is running. It would use more long term resources, but it would also make them quicker to access. While using `include` would use less resources long term, but it would have to load up `functions.cfm` every time one of the calling `CFCs` call it; making it slower, and potentially eating more short term resources.

The "best" choice would depend more on which feature is more important to your setting.

I am also curious why you transfer the `application.functions` to `variables.functions`. As long as the methods inside of `functions.cfm` don't write into the application scope - which should be locked at the method's local level - you should be able to simply reference them in the application scope.

Comment: You can overwrite variables in the `application` scope whenever you want, no need to restart the application (by means of calling `applicationStop()`). Addressing a persistent scope such as `application`, `request` and `session` directly in a component/function is considered bad practise. Always inject dependencies to separate sources of potential errors.

Comment: `I am also curious why you transfer the application.functions to variables.functions` because, while I like to scope everything, I don't scope functions, and if I did, I wouldn't want to type `#application.fn.MyThing()#` for every function.